# Boltzmann distribution from the microcanonical ensemble of ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In the book of *Statistical Physics of Particles* by Kardar, at page 107, it is given that

[image]

However, if the ratio of the factorials is appromated by $(3N/2)^(3/2)$, then the expression for $p(\vec p_1)$ becomes

$$p(\vec p_1) = \left( 1 - \frac{\vec p_1^2}{2mE} \right)^{3N/2 - 2} * (\frac{3N}{4m\pi E})^{3/2}$$

However, in the $N\to \infty$ limit, this expression doesn't converge to an exponential. For that to happen, the expression $\vec p_1^2/(2mE)$ would need to be something like $\vec p_1^2/(N2mE)$, but that is not the case.

So given this, how can the author justfies the logic behind his derivation?

Answer (score 1):

The thermodynamic limit in the microcanonical ensemble corresponds to the limit where $E$, $V$, and $N$ diverge, by keeping constant the ratio between any pair of these quantities. Therefore, the expression you provide does converge to an exponential function.

More in details, let's remember that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e;~~~{\mathrm {and~~then}}~~~~~~~~~~\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^a.
$$
In your final expression
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{\vec p_1^2}{2mE} \right)^{3N/2 - 2}
$$
for $N \rightarrow \infty$, $3N/2 - 2$ diverges like $n=3N/2$, so, introducing $a=-\frac{\vec p_1^2}{2mE}\frac{3N}{2}$, we get the final exponential function.

Comment: But it says it converges to $$p\left(\vec{p}_{1}\right)=\left(\frac{3 N}{4 \pi m E}\right)^{3 / 2} \exp \left(-\frac{3 N}{2} \frac{\vec{p}_{1}^{2}}{2 m E}\right)$$. Where dose that $3N/2$ in the exponential come from?

Comment: @Our  I have added the explicit steps.